# How to make jquery select the right ROW?

Tags: jquery

Helo friends, I need help with jquery parent > selector, i cant make it to select only the current row where mouse is over.

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="hidden" id="url" value="http://style">
        <div id="link">
            <a href="#" id="but"></a>
            <div id="showiframe" style="display: none;">              
                <iframe id="display"></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>

        $('#link a#but').mouseover(function() {
            $(this).parent("div").find('#showiframe').show();
            $(this).parent("div").find("#display").attr('src', $('#url').val());
        });
        $('#showiframe').mouseout(function() {
            $(this).hide();
        });
```

So, how to make this work for each row separately? Every row will have different VALUE in #url.

And also it must work on mouseover...

Please help! Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't use IDs but classes instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use IDs in your selectors
they must generate dynamically, but you can change your code to this

```
$(document).ready ( function () {
    $('div a').hover(function () {
        var p = $(this).parent("div");
        var url = p.siblings('input').val();
        p.find('div').show();
        p.find('iframe').attr('src', url);
    }, function () {
        $(this).siblings('div').hide();
    });
});
```